# Clarification of Magnetization Definition

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm reading a [publication](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmmm.2018.02.003) and trying to understand a simple part that has me caught up:

> Equations for the field inside and outside a longitudinally magnetized, finite cylinder were first retrieved by Callaghan and Maslen. They obtained their result by considering a finite cylinder as a collection of current loops (i.e. an ideal solenoid). The total magnetization is *$M \equiv n I$, with $n$ the number of turns per unit of length and $I$ the current per turn*.

Basically, I can't tell if this is trying to say $M= \frac{N}{L} i$ or $M= \frac{N}{L}Ni$ where $n=\frac{N}{L}$ and $i=\frac{I}{N}$. Since magnetization is $A/m$ and N is unitless, all these solutions are correct unit-wise. In other words, saying current per turn confuses me and I am not sure if I need to then multiply by the number of turns to get the total current or if that is already being applied when multiplied by n. I have seen online how when $B$ is defined for a solenoid, it uses $\frac{N}{L} I$ where $I$ is the total current $I = I \cdot N$, but then became uncertain when they said "Current per turn" for that too instead of total current.

Comment: In the future, please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Ok, will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solenoid, the current passing through each loop is the same: it is the total current going through the solenoid. It is a bit weird for them to say "current per loop", since charge conservation forces the current to be the same at every point in the solenoidal wire.

**Edit:** this holds for a closed circuit (see Wald's (*Advanced Classical Electromagnetism*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism), Chap. 4, Problem 1). However, since the paper concerns uniform magnetization, the current on each loop should be the same by assumption.

In other words, $I$ is indeed the total current.

**Alternative Arguments**

The magnetization can be obtained from the magnetic field, which can be computed by Ampère's Law. The field is indeed $B = \mu_0 n I$ (SI units), where $n$ is the number of turns per unit length and $I$ is the total current.

Alternatively, notice that $M = \frac{N}{L} i = \frac{I}{L}$, and hence the magnetization would not depend on the total number of loops. However, passing more loops through the same length does mean there is more current going through an Ampèrian loop, and hence the field should be stronger. Therefore, the magnetization should grow with $N$.

Comment: Yes, their wording for that is what threw me off so much. I knew it had to depend on # of loops, but was second guessing myself when they worded it like that. Thank you so much for the thorough explanation!